# MySQL Select DISTINCT multiple columns based on the uniqueness of one row?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand what this query does exactly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `state`, `state_name` FROM `geo` ORDER BY `state_name` ASC
```

All I'm trying to do is select 2 columns (state and state_name), I want only unique rows that do not have duplicate values for the state field. I don't care if there are duplicate values in the state_name field.

Is my query checking both columns for uniqueness or just state?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DISTINCT will return only distinct rows, so:

> Is my query checking both columns for uniqueness or just state?

Both columns

You could also switch to GROUP BY instead.

```
SELECT `state`, `state_name` FROM `geo` group by 'state', 'state_name' ORDER BY `state_name` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It's checking for unique combinations of state and state_name. Distinct operates on all columns included in your select list.

To only include unique state values, just select distinct state