# How group rows with a sorted?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `recordstouser` 
GROUP BY IdUserRecordstouser 
ORDER BY IdRecordstouser DESC;
```

In a table there is a field `StatusRecordstouser` which can take values 0/1.
So I need get grouped rows by `IdUserRecordstouser` such as at grouped row will be a row wtih `StatusRecordstouser = 0;`

**For example:**

```
id | StatusRecordstouser | IdUserRecordstouser
1    1                     2
2    1                     2
3    0                     2
4    0                     3
```

**Output 2 row:**

```
4 | 0 | 3
3 | 0 | 2
```

**The most correct version:**

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `recordstouser` WHERE StatusRecordstouser = 0 ) t 
JOIN detailtousers ON detailtousers.idDetailToUsers = t.IdUserRecordstouser 
WHERE t.IdtoUserRecordstouser = 458 
GROUP BY t.IdUserRecordstouser ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

**Error:**

```
Unknown column 't.IdtoUserRecordstouser' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: what about this: 

SELECT *
FROM FROM `recordstouser`
ORDER BY IdUserRecordstouser DESC

Comment: Who have set me minus point? If you have nothing to do more - leave the site

Comment: Please, look at question scheme, you give me not correct examplesю I did not set to you minus. I am sure

Comment: No one hates you: your question seems too difficult because it is not clear what you are asking. No one understands what you want to do. Take time to reedit your question.

Comment: I can not use chat, have not points

Comment: Ahmed: you can edit your question even if you have no points.

Comment: @AhmedFaud your question just doesn't make sense. You've said you need all rows with 0 or 1 but why doesn't your result set include anything with a 1? Do you mean to say that if there is no row with a status 0, show a row with status 1 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I know you said you can't use WHERE, but this is a bit different. You can see the results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b5a0/11

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM `recordstouser`
  WHERE StatusRecordstouser = 0
) t
GROUP BY t.IdUserRecordstouser
ORDER BY t.id DESC;
```

You could also `ORDER BY t.StatusRecordstouser ASC` instead of `ORDER BY t.id DESC` to get 0's first.

Comment: Are you trying to join the results of this query to another table?

Answer (score 3):

Group function: use `MAX()`, `MIN()` MySQL.

Second case:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM `recordstouser` GROUP BY IdUserRecordstouser) as data
ORDER BY IdRecordstouser;
```

Comment: Does not work correct this query, it return me row wuth a status = 1

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need `group by`?  Just use `where`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `recordstouser`
WHERE IdRecordstouser = 0;
```

EDTI:

So, you want a *preference* for 0, if that row is available.

You can do this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM recordstouser rtu
WHERE IdRecordstouser = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM recordstouser rtu
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM recordstouser rtu2
                  WHERE rtu2.IdUserRecordstouser = rtu.IdUserRecordstouser AND rtu2.IdRecordstouser = 0
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM recordstouser rtu2
                  WHERE rtu2.IdUserRecordstouser = rtu.IdUserRecordstouser AND rtu2.Id > rt.Id
                 );
```

This assumes that there are other columns in the table.  For your data (and reasonable variants thereof), this would work:

```
SELECT id, StatusRecordstouser, IdUserRecordstouser
FROM recordstouser rtu
WHERE IdRecordstouser = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(id), 1, IdUserRecordstouser
FROM recordstouser rtu
GROUP BY rtu.IdUserRecordstouser
HAVING SUM(IdRecordstouser = 0) = 0;
```

Comment: WHERE can not use, I need get all rows with a 0/1, but if 0 - show it at first

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to me that you only want to show rows where the 'statusrecordstouser' column is 0 (for each user) but if that does not exist, show one where 'statusrecordstouser' is 1. If that is correct, consider something like this.

```
SELECT MAX(id), statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
FROM myTable
GROUP BY statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
ORDER BY iduserrecordstouser, statusrecordstouser;
```

This will return two rows if the user has a 0 and a 1, or one row if they only have one or the other. I have ordered to put them in an order that matches what you want (0 row will always go first). I used the max to get the latest row if a group occured more than once.

To show what I mean, this is what the output of the above query is:

```
| id | status | idUser |
+----+--------+--------+
| 3  |   0    |   2    |
+----+--------+--------+
| 2  |   1    |   2    |
+----+--------+--------+
| 4  |   0    |   3    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Now, the question is how do you differentiate between the two rows? Well, you don't have to, you want to just take the first from each grouping because if it's 0 you'll take it, and if there is no 0 then it will be 1 and you can take that too. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808755/mysql-using-sql-having-trouble-figuring-out-the-busiest-hour-for-each-day-that/26809152#26809152) for how to get the first item from a group.

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.statusrecordstouser, t.iduserrecordstouser
FROM(SELECT MAX(id) AS id, statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
    ORDER BY iduserrecordstouser, statusrecordstouser
    ) t
WHERE(SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM(SELECT MAX(id) AS id, statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
          FROM myTable
          GROUP BY statusrecordstouser, iduserrecordstouser
          ORDER BY iduserrecordstouser, statusrecordstouser
      ) tt
      WHERE tt.iduserrecordstouser = t.iduserrecordstouser AND tt.statusrecordstouser <= t.statusrecordstouser
) <= 1;
```

I tested this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12ac/1) and it worked. I even added a row that only had status 1 to make sure it worked.