# Select four items for each group?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, join, group-by

I have got two tables, first one called `card`:

```
| card_id | card_name |
```

And table `withdrawal`:

```
| withdrawal_id | card_id | transaction_date |
```

I want to get the last four transaction_dates for each card_id.

I tried this code but it wouldn't give the last 4 dates:

```
SELECT a.card_id, b.transaction_date
FROM card AS a 
JOIN withdrawal AS b ON a.card_id = b.card_id
GROUP BY a.card_id, b.transaction_date
ORDER BY a.card_id, b.transaction_date
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: This is a quite frequent question that has been answered many times before. These are some similar questions (& answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to get the first N rows per group, which can be done using something like this:

```
SELECT a.card_id, b.transaction_date
FROM card a
JOIN withdrawal b ON a.card_id = b.card_id
WHERE(
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM card c
   JOIN withdrawal w ON w.card_id = c.card_id
   WHERE c.card_id = a.card_id AND w.transaction_date <= b.transaction_date
) <= 4
ORDER BY a.card_id, b.transaction_date
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677063/select-unique-records-limit-with-n-rows/26678295#26678295) for more info on getting rows per group.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept this answer if it worked. Also, bookmark this [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) if you ever have a problem like this again and are looking for different ways to do it.

Comment: @pdpandya I've notive that if you don't need anything else from the card table, just the card_id, you don't need to do a join since you can get the card_id from the withdrawal table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving it

```
select 
w.withdrawal_id,
w.card_id,
w.transaction_date
from card c
left join 
(
  select 
  r1.*
  from withdrawal r1
  where 
  (
    select count(*)
    from withdrawal r2
    where r1.card_id = r2.card_id
    AND r1.transaction_date <= r2.transaction_date
  ) <=4
  order by r1.transaction_date desc
)w
on w.card_id = c.card_id
order by c.card_id
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f098f/2)**